# Wine Photoshop CS6 broken fonts

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux

I successfully installed and ran Adobe Photoshop CS6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 OS. However, fonts are broken. Some of fonts just have different style, while some are not displayed at all.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTHHc.jpg)

Check screenshot. (top bar) The problem is that some of tools are not able to be used if font is not displayed.

I use 32bit version of Photoshop CS6.
Similar issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226897

Comment: I think that this is an Wine application error, I am not entirely sure who manages the fonts for Wine applications, but I think it is Wine itself and it doesn't use any of the presets in Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you try installing `corefonts` and `allfonts` with winetricks?

Comment: @Hi-Angel Yes, it doesnt seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of advanced issues, I suggest to look into others Wine users reports : https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=17